# Eurocity Train Numbers

Tags: trains, europe, international-travel

I'm looking at taking a train from Dresden to Bratislava. According to DB from Dresden to Prague it's EC171 and from Prague to Bratislava it's EC279. Could this be the same train, just changing numbers, or is it two different trains? It could make a difference for the connection (not having to change platforms).

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the composition of the trains [EC171](http://www.vagonweb.cz/razeni/vlak.php?zeme=CD&kategorie=EC&cislo=171&nazev=Carl%20Maria%20von%20Weber&rok=2018&lang=de) and [EC279](http://www.vagonweb.cz/razeni/vlak.php?zeme=CD&kategorie=EC&cislo=279&nazev=Metropolitan&rok=2018&lang=de), they are operated with different engines and cars and are not the same train.